# How to Install Linux Packages through Python

Tags: python

I am wondering how to check the sources.list for a specific source, ex:

```
http://exa.mple.net/debian jessie main
```

And if it does not exist, add the source.

Then, install the package if it does not exist. Also, how do you call that program, like vnstat, and store values in variables in python.

Comment: Can you be more specific, like give an example of the code you want to run to add the source?

Comment: I want to run "echo [source] > /etc/apt/sources.list"

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 to be exact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need root permissions to write to the /etc/apt directory in Ubuntu, this is best carried out in the Terminal

```
 sudo apt-add-repository ftp://deb.multimedia.org/debian jessie main non-free
```

Comment: I will use an external script.